# Creating a column with a specified date/time format on Oracle +

Tags: oracle

I am working on a set of tables for an assignment related to airports,

```
CREATE TABLE FLIGHT
(FlightCode VARCHAR2(6),
AirplaneSerialNum VARCHAR2(6) NOT NULL,
RemCapacity NUMBER(3),
FlightDate DATE NOT NULL,
RouteNum NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
FlightDeparture DATE,
FlightArrival DATE,
CONSTRAINT FlightPK PRIMARY KEY (FlightCode),
CONSTRAINT RouteFK FOREIGN KEY (RouteNum) REFERENCES ROUTE (RouteNum));
```

Where FlightDeparture and FlightArrival are ideally referenced in the 24H format or 12H format (HHMM), how should I go about writing it, and how can I make a column in a separate table referencing the difference (to 2dp.) in number of hours between FlightArrival and FlightDeparture?

e.g. in another table that references FlightCode in FLIGHT as a FK

```
HoursInFlight NUMBER(10,2)
where HoursInFlight = FlightArrival - FlightDeparture
```

Comment: It's usually a bad idea to store date/time values as strings or number. Keep the `DATE` data type. If you need only the time part, then simply ignore the date part of the value.

Comment: The DATE data type does not have a format. The representation of DATE as a string does. You should store dates in the DATE data type (or TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE - see below); then - if you need to display those dates often in a specific format - write a ***view*** selecting `to_char(<date column[s] in specific format>)`. The calculation of date differences should also **not** be stored, but rather included in a ***view***. Lastly, flights are often over different time zones; the DATE data type is not appropriate for such use - use TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE instead.

Answer (score 1):

`DATE` datatype looks OK; it stores values in Oracle's *internal* format, so it is up to you how will you display them to users. For example:

Inserting:

```
SQL> create table flight (flight_date date);

Table created.

SQL> insert into flight (flight_date) values (sysdate);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into flight (flight_date) values (to_date('18.07.2021 16:58', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:Mi'));

1 row created.
```

Selecting (various options):

```
SQL> select * from flight;

FLIGHT_D
--------
18.07.21
18.07.21

SQL> select to_char(flight_date, 'dd-mon-yy hh:mi am', 'nls_date_language = english')) val from flight;
select to_char(flight_date, 'dd-mon-yy hh:mi am', 'nls_date_language = english')) val from flight
                                                                                *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected


SQL> select to_char(flight_date, 'dd-mon-yy hh:mi am', 'nls_date_language = english') val from flight;

VAL
---------------------------
18-jul-21 04:58 PM
18-jul-21 04:58 PM

SQL> select to_char(flight_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') val from flight;

VAL
-------------------
18/07/2021 16:58:36
18/07/2021 16:58:00

SQL> alter session set nls_Date_Format = 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi am';

Session altered.

SQL> select * from flight;

FLIGHT_DATE
-------------------
2021-07-18 04:58 PM
2021-07-18 04:58 PM

SQL>
```

---

The difference of two `DATE` values is number of days between them, so - if you want to "convert" them to hours, multiply it by 24 (as there are 24 hours in a day):

```
SQL> select to_date('18.07.2021 17:02', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') - to_date('18.07.2021 10:44', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi') diff
  2  from dual;

      DIFF
----------
     ,2625

SQL> select 0.2625 * 24 hours from dual;

     HOURS
----------
       6,3

SQL>
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, the example worked out to be very helpful! So if I would need to share viewing of my work through GRANT to someone else, they will see the dates and times based on the date format they are using?

Comment: By default, yes. If you're creating a report for them, then it is your responsibility to present values the way you find the most appropriate. If they are selecting values, then it is up to them.